# Can we create a new op-pending command in Vim?

Tags: vim

Does anyone know if it's possible to create a new op-pending command?

e.g. I'd like to replace a sequence such as `vf(r<space>w` with `,cf(`. Specifically here, the idea is to "clear" the text from the cursor position up to and including the next opening brace and then put the cursor at the beginning of the next word.

I may just be missing something in the help files (or my Google-fu is off today), so a pointer to the right place would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hmm, what would be the pending part, the motion? Just to confirm, if used `,cW` it would clear up to the next WORD and then position the cursor on the next word, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think [:h map-operator](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/map.html#%3amap-operator) is what you're looking for.

Comment: Yeah, i /just/ found that... duh! :)  Thanks a lot

Comment: Glad to help you, Derek. I started in Vim with your screencasts :-) by the way, just updated the answer with a specific solution.

Comment: @peter's below is a more correct solution, I think so we should have people look at that.  It's pretty darn close to the information in the Vim help, which we all know is awesome... I just couldn't find it :)

Comment: @Derek : Ouch, just noticed Peter posted it. I should refresh pages in Stack Overflow more often; just tried to provide the smaller possible solution… Peter deserves this correct checkmark!

Comment: I disagree. We should be pointing people at the canonical spot - the Vim help!  Not that Peter's help wasn't appreciated :)

Answer (score 4):

You want to use `:set opfunc` and `g@`. The documentation is pretty good, `:h g@`.

```
nnoremap <silent> ,c :set opfunc=Clearing<cr>g@
vnoremap <silent> ,c :<c-u>set opfunc=Clearing<cr>g@

function! Clearing(type, ...)
  let sel_save = &selection
  let &selection = "inclusive"
  let reg_save = @@

  if a:0  " Invoked from Visual mode, use '< and '> marks.
    silent exe "normal! `<" . a:type . "`>r "
  elseif a:type == 'line'
    silent exe "normal! '[V']r "
  elseif a:type == 'block'
    silent exe "normal! `[\<C-V>`]r "
  else
    silent exe "normal! `[v`]r "
  endif
  norm! `]w

  let &selection = sel_save
  let @@ = reg_save
endfunction
```

Comment: Cheers.  I was just too blind to see the help.

Comment: @Derek: glad to help. Thank you for your screencasts.